# Android - Get Notified when a new access point is detected?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

Does Android provide a notification of being in vicinity of a new Wifi Network? Whether the device is configured to connect to that wifi network depends on whether the device has the wifi configuration set for that particular wifi network, but is it possible to get notification whenever entering any new wifi network?
I saw the WifiManager class but the states inside the class do not seem to achieve what I am trying to do. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use service which will check the wifi network for particular interval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` registered to receive intents with action: `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`.

In this BroadcastReceiver, you can extract a [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) object from the intent:

```
NetworkInfo ni = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
```

Then process `ni.getState()` to check connections/disconnections from wifi networks.

Is this what you were looking for?

---

*Edit after answer*

So if you want to know which wifi networks are available, use [WifiManager.getScanResults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29) This gives you the list of nearby access points in `Scanresult` objects. Those contain the SSID and BSSID of the access points, which are respectively their network name and mac address.

You can get this information asynchronously by using a `BroadcastReceiver` registered to receive intents with action `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`. Then you will be notified each time the system performs a wifi scan, and you can check if a new SSID (i.e. network name) has appeared since the last scan.

And finally if you wish to scan more often than the system does by default, you can trigger wifi scans yourself using `WifiManager.startScan()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not give the indication of new wifi network does it? I think It gives changes in the states of the connected network

Comment: Thanks! I needed the second scenario solution. Registering with WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION. Thanks a lot, I will check it out and hope it works this way :)